# Redux state is undefined in mapStateToProps couldn't find the issue

Tags: reactjs

I cannot find out my error. I tried lot of answers in stackoverflow but those didn't work for me.

This is my Reducer: **IcmWebReducer.js**

```
    const initialState = {
    invoices : [],
    params: {
        status: 'Pending',
        _sort: 'documentInfo.dueDate',
        _order: 'desc',
        q: ''
     }
    };

    const IcmWebReducer = (state = initialState, action) =>{
    switch (action.type){
        case 'UPDATE_INVOICES':
            return Object.assign({}, state, {
                invoices: action.invoices
            });
        case 'UPDATE_PARAMS':
            return Object.assign({}, state, {
                params: action.params
            });
        default:
            return state;
    }
   };

export default IcmWebReducer;
```

This is my **App.js**

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import './App.scss';

import Header from './components/header/Header'
import InvoiceAudit from "./components/invoice/InvoiceAudit";

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
        <div className="App container">
            <Header/>
         /*   <InvoiceAudit store = {this.props.store}/> */
            <InvoiceAudit/>
        </div>
    );
 } 
}

export default App;
```

This is the **index.js**

```
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { createStore } from 'redux';
import IcmWebReducer from "./reducers/IcmWebReducer";

let store = createStore(IcmWebReducer);

ReactDOM.render(
 <Provider store={store}>
 <App/>
 </Provider>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

This is the class that i am using mapStateToProps method

```
    const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    console.log(state);
    return {
        invoices: state.IcmWebReducer,
    }
};
```

This showed me undefined in console.log . but i can't find the error. I am returning the default state in my reducer also. Can anyone help me

Comment: Where are you using `mapStateToProps`?

Comment: While exporting app, you should use connect like; export default connect(mapStateToProps)(App)

Comment: I am using mapStateToProps inside invoiceAudit component. Should we used reducer name inside mapStateToProps or can we directly access through state param

Answer (score 0):

While exporting your app, you should use `connect`;

```
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(App)
```

This might help solve your problem;

```
const ConnectedApp = connect(mapStateToProps)(App);
```

And in `index.js`;

```
ReactDOM.render(< Provider store={store}>< ConnectedApp /></Provider>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Also in your mapStateToProps, this would suffice

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
console.log(state);
return {
    invoices: state.invoices,
    //status: state.params.status -> like this
}
```

I believe problem might be that your invoices state is trying to take whole reducer initial state rather than just invoices empty array.

Answer (score 0):

Your App component should use connect method

App component should be like below snippet

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {connect} from "react-redux";
import './App.scss';

import Header from './components/header/Header'
import InvoiceAudit from "./components/invoice/InvoiceAudit";

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
        <div className="App container">
            <Header/>
            <InvoiceAudit/>
        </div>
    );
 } 
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({invoices: state.IcmWebReducer});

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(App);
```